# Adding a checkbox to a button?

Tags: android, button, checkbox

I created a button programmatically:

```
Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
button.setTextSize(30);
button.setGravity(Gravity.START);
button.setText("Button");
```

Now I want to add a CheckBox to the button. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Button is a View and Checkbox is a view, you cannot add a view to another view unless it is a view group. So basically, you need to create a layout (ViewGroup) such as LinearLayout and then add button and checkbox to that layout

Answer (score 0):

You can create a checkBox and handle the event click on it with OnClickListener.

You aren't able to do this please comment this answer and I'll help you :)